# Oracle - Where clause having null value condition does not give corresponding result

Tags: oracle

Oracle RDBMS :18C

I have a sample data here.
https://dbfiddle.uk/qbB_JLRp.
[image: Sample table]

I want to get ColD,E,F result based on conditions in with-clause,
ie. ColA,COLB and COLC.
[image: Condition string]

ColA,B,C conditional string is of user's choice. So it may change from time to time. (I use vba userform to collect user's choice and make a with-clause string via vba, so no worry to dynamic with-clause string)

My question is how to get correct result when condition string in with-clause have '' value？(highlighted in orange brush)
[image: null value condition]

I tried to change '' to null in with-clause,but it doesn't work. No corresponding rows were retreived when there's a null value condition in with-clause. For example, condition2 in with-clause should've retreived 3 records below.
[image: 3 records should've been retreived]

It seems that **each** null value condition has to especially specified like below in order to get correct result.
[image: Specify column to be null]

In this way, the where-clause,however,will be very long and complicated because I'll have to especially specified each null value codition in where-clause whenever there's one in with-clause.

Hope my expression is clear.
If there's a way to work around with-clause and make little adjustment to where-clause, I'll be very much appreciated.

'--------------------------------------
According to **@The Impaler**'s answer, I dig a little deeper about '**IS NOT DISTINCT FROM**' operator. Google's first result gives a good insight about why my original query is not working on Null value. (Probably '**in**' operator is using **equal** comparison operator.)

Here's google's results on 'IS NOT DISTINCT FROM' operator:
[image: IS NOT DISTINCT FROM operator]

Hope this google result help someone like me who needs a more concret explaination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the SQL Standard's `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` operator that, unfortunately, is not implemented in Oracle. Nevertheless, it can be simulated with `DECODE()`.

For example, you can do:

```
with Desired_Column_Combination as (
  Select 'A1' ColA,'B2' ColB,'C2' ColC from dual union all 
  Select 'A1' ColA,'B1' ColB,'' ColC from dual union all --Should've 3 records
  Select 'A2' ColA,'' ColB,'C3' ColC from dual union all --Should've 2 records
  Select 'A3' ColA,'B1' ColB,'C1' ColC from dual
)
select * 
from SampleTable S
where exists (
  select 1
  from Desired_Column_Combination d
  where decode(s.ColA, d.ColA, 1, 0) = 1
    and decode(s.ColB, d.ColB, 1, 0) = 1
    and decode(s.ColC, d.ColC, 1, 0) = 1
);
```

Result:

```
 COLA  COLB  COLC  DESIRED_COLD  DESIRED_COLE  DESIRED_COLF 
 ----- ----- ----- ------------- ------------- ------------ 
 A1    B1    null  28            24            23           
 A1    B1    null  13            90            36           
 A1    B1    null  27            27            82           
 A1    B2    C2    54            58            34           
 A2    null  C3    22            27            12           
 A2    null  C3    14            78            50           
 A3    B1    C1    44            70            53           
 A3    B1    C1    38            13            11
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CRGeYc8C).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I'm looking for. I'm looking for something that final query wording won't grow too much. Because with-clasue depends on user's input. The number of combination in with-clause may grow up to 50 or even higher. My actual number of conditional columns is 10,  by using your idea (decode), I only have to expand where clause to 10 lines regardless of the size of with-clause conditions.

Comment: can we make exists operator faster? For performance improvement, I open an new thread here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76794714/oracle-make-a-correlated-query-more-efficient

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember "NULL is not equal to anything - **not even to itself**."

Borrowing and adjusting code from your Fiddle:

```
With Desired_Column_Combination as (
-- Select 'A1' ColA,'B2' ColB,'C2' ColC from dual union all 
Select 'A1' ColA,'B1' ColB, null ColC from dual -- union all --Should've 3 records
-- Select 'A2' ColA,'' ColB,'C3' ColC from dual -- union all --Should've 2 records
-- Select 'A3' ColA,'B1' ColB,'C1' ColC from dual
  )
Select * from SampleTable S
where (ColA,ColB,ColC) 
  in (Select ColA,ColB,ColC from Desired_Column_Combination)
union all
Select * from SampleTable S
where (ColA,ColB) 
  in (Select ColA,ColB from Desired_Column_Combination)
 and ColC is null
union all
Select * from SampleTable S
where (ColA,ColC) 
  in (Select ColA,ColC from Desired_Column_Combination)
 and ColB is null
```

[returns three rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/56fBKKf7).

```
With Desired_Column_Combination as (
-- Select 'A1' ColA,'B2' ColB,'C2' ColC from dual union all 
-- Select 'A1' ColA,'B1' ColB, null ColC from dual -- union all --Should've 3 records
Select 'A2' ColA,'' ColB,'C3' ColC from dual -- union all --Should've 2 records
-- Select 'A3' ColA,'B1' ColB,'C1' ColC from dual
  )
Select * from SampleTable S
where (ColA,ColB,ColC) 
  in (Select ColA,ColB,ColC from Desired_Column_Combination)
union all
Select * from SampleTable S
where (ColA,ColB) 
  in (Select ColA,ColB from Desired_Column_Combination)
 and ColC is null
union all
Select * from SampleTable S
where (ColA,ColC) 
  in (Select ColA,ColC from Desired_Column_Combination)
 and ColB is null
```

[returns two rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/yUbmssiX).

So you need to cater appropriately for NULL values in your selection from **Desired_Column_Combination**.

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I know that 'union' operator can get correct result. But this make where-clause very long and complicated since in reality there's 10 conditional columns (not just ColA,B,C). If the amount of user's input in with-clause grows to 20 or more conditions, then I'll have to dynamically repeat Select  ... union
 all (Select ... union) all

Comment: 'union' operator is 1 to 1 ratio, meaning whenever users choose 1 more condition in with-clause then (Select ... union all) pattern has to dynamically increase 1 time, which is not likely expandable since with-clause condition is not under control.

Comment: @jouyungcheng: Well, it should probably be possibly to generate the `UNION`ed `SELECT`s.  But @TheImpaler's suggestion is sure much more straightforward and 
 easier to maintain.

Comment: performance wise, maybe Select+union or In+Specify null column is a better solution. I'm looking for a faster solution, do you have any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76794714/oracle-make-a-correlated-query-more-efficient

Comment: @jouyungcheng: For performance, I'd check, whether cutting out the **Desired_Column_Combination** altogether (using generated `WHERE` clauses) would help.

Comment: @jouyungcheng: Syntax-wise, you could use `select S.* from SampleTable S where (nvl(S.ColA, ' '), nvl(S.ColB, ' '), nvl(S.ColC, ' ')) in (select nvl(D.ColA, ' '), nvl(D.ColB, ' '), nvl(D.ColC, ' ') from Desired_Column_Combination D)
;` - benefitting from the index, Paul W suggested.