# Oracle - Make a correlated query more efficient

Tags: oracle, exists, correlated-subquery

Oracle RDBMS :18C

This topic is subsequent to my previous thread:
[Oracle - Where clause having null value condition does not give corresponding result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76790252/oracle-where-clause-having-null-value-condition-does-not-give-corresponding-re)

Because the last question is solved (to obtain correct results), I closed it.
This is an another issue,regarding performance, so I raise this new question.
To make my question clearer,please read through above link first.

**The Impaler**'s answer to last post using **decode** is just what I need.
But later I found that query is not very efficient because my outer table is much bigger than the inner table, which maybe the cause slowing down the query (compare to **in** operator, see speed test table below)

Due to proprietary concern, I can't upload my atual working table.
That being said, let me take below small sample table to explain my actual working table:
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/13wvoqtM)

```
With Desired_Column_Combination as (
  Select 'A1' ColA,'B2' ColB,'C2' ColC from dual union all 
  Select 'A1' ColA,'B1' ColB,'' ColC from dual union all --Should've 3 records
  Select 'A2' ColA,'' ColB,'C3' ColC from dual union all --Should've 2 records
  Select 'A3' ColA,'B1' ColB,'C1' ColC from dual
)
select * 
from SampleTable S
where exists (
  select 1 from Desired_Column_Combination d
  where decode(s.ColA, d.ColA, 1, 0) = 1
    and decode(s.ColB, d.ColB, 1, 0) = 1
    and decode(s.ColC, d.ColC, 1, 0) = 1
);
```

In my atual working table:
<1>. Desired_Column_Combination is of user's choice and the amount of condition may up to 70 **select ... from...**. I use VBA to make a dynamic Desired_Column_Combination table based on user's choice.
<2>. All condition in Desired_Column_Combination is 100% from SampleTable, so there's at least 1 record in SampleTable corresponds to it in Desired_Column_Combination Table.  In other words, **Desired_Column_Combination table is a subset of SampleTable.**
<3>. SampleTable have indices on ColA,B and C.
<4>. I only have query table priviledge, can't delete/update/alter table.

I then tried to understand **exists** operator, hoping solve it by myself.
Here's a brief conclusion after a few hours of gooling:
Generally, if outer table is much larger than inner table, then using **in** operator is better. On the other hand, if inner table contains more rows than outer table and inner table have indices, then using **exists** is faster than **in**.

Then I do some speed test on my working table:
[image: Speed Test]

It seems the test results is the same as my google conclusion, because my outer table, SampleTable, is much larger than inner table, Desired_Column_Combination, so **exists** operator gives worse performance than **in** operator.

My question is:
<1>.  Is there a way to use **in** operator while not expand where-clause too much?  (To my best knowledge, in order to use **in** under null value query, we need to specify every column to be null in where-clause whenever Desired_Column_Combination has a null value condition)
<2>.  If **exists** is the only answer, can we re-write the query such that outer table becomes inner table and vice versa to make **exists** runs faster?

Comment: Why use decode at all? Why not just three predicates joining s to d?

Comment: @PaulW Because join operation will use equal operator like table1.ColA=table2.ColA, and the result will have only none null values, which is why TheImpaler in the previous post suggest use decode.

Comment: @PaulW https://dbfiddle.uk/oFQG6uhS.  Please see solution 4 using inner join. Only 3 record is retreived.

Comment: Replied via an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with the `DECODE` solution is that it cannot be indexed because the function has inputs from two different tables. If it's simply `NULL`-handling and you want the benefit of indexes, I suggest a simple `NVL` function and a matching index.

```
select * 
from SampleTable S
where exists (
  select 1 from Desired_Column_Combination d
  where NVL(s.ColA,' ') = NVL(d.ColA,' ')
    and NVL(s.ColB,' ') = NVL(d.ColB,' ')
    and NVL(s.ColC,' ') = NVL(d.ColC,' ')
);
```

Now a matching index, and it's best to include all three columns when doing so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE INDEX index1 ON Desired_Column_Combination 
(NVL(colA,' '),NVL(colB,' '),NVL(colC,' '))
```

FYI, the reason for Oracle's default `NULL` logic is that `NULL` isn't intended to be a meaningful value that contributes to a row's identity. It is intended rather to mean "unknown" or nothing meaningful - it denotes the *lack* of anything meaningful, so normally you wouldn't want to find child rows if the join key columns have a `NULL` value in them. Such a row's identity would be undefined, unknowable, and uncertain. There are of course exceptions (e.g. when metadata is part of the key, like in type-2 history tables where you don't want to use an imaginary end date), and so Oracle allows it, but you have to do a bit of extra work to get them to be treated like meaningful key values that are part of a row's identity. `NVL` is the easiest way to do that, but applying a function to the column throws out index use unless you create a corresponding function-based index to match. But often when you find yourself in this situation there's something wrong with your data model, where `NULL` is being used in a matter it wasn't intended for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Since we're using NVL, could we use inner join + NVL? Because my outer table is much bigger than inner table, so I think maybe in operator is faster?

Comment: Can you explain more detail about what is a matching index? I only have read/query privilege, can I create matching index?

Comment: An index with columns matching the columns your query predicate is filtering on. So colA,colB and colC together. Further, since you have to apply a function like NVL to each in order to treat NULL as a real value, you need the index definition to employ the exact same function, just as I showed in my answer above. Otherwise, Oracle can't use the index. You will have to talk to your DBA or the schema owner about creating an index for you if you are a read-only user.

Comment: I've tested your code, it turns out to be surprisingly fast! That's really amazing! I only use index of SampleTable, and it only takes 22 sec to run 81 combinations in Desire_column_combination tables. Holy.. Thanks Paul

Comment: I'm glad you're happy, but 22 seconds for 81 lookups is extremely slow. It should be more like a hundredth of a second. If the index I recommended were there it probably would be.

Comment: Yes, the db has about 7.3million rows which is not very big. But I think this is the fastest and correct way I can use for now. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AND` and `OR` instead of `DECODE`:

```sql
With Desired_Column_Combination (colA, ColB, colC) as (
  Select 'A1', 'B2', 'C2' from dual union all 
  Select 'A1', 'B1', NULL from dual union all
  Select 'A2', NULL, 'C3' from dual union all
  Select 'A3', 'B1', 'C1' from dual
)
SELECT * 
FROM   SampleTable S
WHERE  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   Desired_Column_Combination d
  WHERE  (s.ColA = d.ColA OR (s.colA IS NULL AND d.colA IS NULL))
  AND    (s.ColB = d.ColB OR (s.colB IS NULL AND d.colB IS NULL))
  AND    (s.ColC = d.ColC OR (s.colC IS NULL AND d.colC IS NULL))
);
```

Or, since you have a static list of options, you don't need to use `IN`, `EXISTS` or a join and can just use a `WHERE` filter on the main query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   SampleTable S
WHERE  (colA, colB, colC) IN (('A1', 'B2', 'C2'), ('A3', 'B1', 'C1'))
OR     (colB IS NULL AND (colA, colC) IN (('A2', 'C3')))
OR     (colC IS NULL AND (colA, colB) IN (('A1', 'B1')));
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply, for your suggestion 1, can I use in operator plus and/ or ? This indeed give me some inspiration!